# TYPO3 menu: how to set "entryLevel" dynamic?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to create a menu that displays in TYPO3 all subpages and the parent page. My problem is that I find no way to assign `entryLevel` dynamically.

I'm working with TYPO3 6.1
This is currently my typoscript for the menu.

```
lib.mainnavi = HMENU
lib.mainnavi {
    entryLevel = 1 
    1 = TMENU
    1.wrap = <ul> | </ul>
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        NO {
          subst_elementUid = 1
          allWrap = <li id="link{elementUid}" class="first">| |*| <li id="link{elementUid}">| |*| <li id="link{elementUid}" class="last">|
          wrapItemAndSub = |</li>
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
          subst_elementUid = 1
          allWrap = <li id="link{elementUid}" class="first current first_current">| |*| <li id="link{elementUid}" class="current">| |*| <li id="link{elementUid}" class="last current last_current">|          
          wrapItemAndSub = |</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a picture to illustrate what I want.
When I go to "1", I want to see "FAQ", "GTC (EU)" and "GTC (USA)".
When I go to "FAQ", I want to see A-J and "1" as "back".
When I go to "A", I want to see "FAQ" as "back"
[image: TYPO3 pages]

I can make the "back" menu with a seccond menu and `special = browse`. But I can't find a way to set `entryLevel` dynamically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entry level can get positive and negative values.

While the positive values are marking absolute level positions counting from the root page.

```
Root => 0
  - Page => 1
    - Page => 2
      - Current Page => 3
```

negative values will be relative and counted from the current page back to the root

```
Root => -4
  - Page => -3
    -Page => -2
      - Current Page => -1
```

This way you don't have to use conditions for every level, which would just bloat your caching tables.

```
Root => 0
  - Page => 1
    - Current Page => 2

Root => -3
  - Page => -2
    - Current Page => -1
```

Comment: True, true, but how will this work without the conditions for different tree levels? While being on the pages `A, B, C...` the values must be `-2`, and when `FAQ` (below `1`) is active, `-1` and when `1` is active it has to be `1`. Can you post the typoscript code you would use?

Comment: That's just NOT how it works - as I already mentioned -1 will be relative, not absolute, so it will always point to the current page. So do the other negative values, with -2 pointing to the parent page of the current page, -3 pointing to the grand parent and so on.

This way the whole "negative tree" is constantly shifted around, only depending on the page you are currently on. This way you can get rid of conditions completely.

Comment: In this example it should be always -1, since this would just mean: Show me a menu of subpages of the current page only.

Comment: [link](http://books.google.de/books?id=xayL0Ckq60kC&pg=PT491&lpg=PT491&dq=typo3+kochbuch+entrylevel&source=bl&ots=pMwzJVYePD&sig=ISrekyTOxoB-ACtUnxxjgEhUs_E&hl=de&sa=X&ei=MJX2Uai2Aubk4QT-8YCYAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=typo3%20kochbuch%20entrylevel&f=false) that's the part I wrote for the (German) TYPO3 Cookbook explaining how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `entryLevel` setting with a condition below your TS code. Just have a look at the [documentation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/4/1/#id1783025) for the `treeLevel` condition.

Use it like this:

```
[treeLevel = 2]
    lib.mainnavi.entryLevel = 2
[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nother solution, that does not use entryLevel at all:

```
lib.mainnavi = HMENU
lib.mainnavi {
  special = directory
  special.value.field = uid 
    ...
}
```

This would create a menu of pages having the UID of the current page as PID, AKA subpages of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
lib.mainnavi = HMENU
lib.mainnavi {
    entryLevel = 1
    special = directory
    special.value.data = leveluid:-1

    # your code here ...
}
```