# Navigation for »next level« in Page Tree

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I would like to create a menu that always displays the items of the next level relative to the current position on the navigation.

Example: Lets say there is such a page tree:

```
+ Index*
+ + Page 1**
  + - Page 1.1
  + - Page 1.2
  + + Page 1.3
    + - Page 1.3.1
    + - Page 1.3.2
    + - Page 1.3.2
+ + Page 2
  + - Page 2.1
  + + Page 2.2
    + - Page 2.2.1
    + - Page 2.2.2
```

The `*` and `**` mean to be the current Page the user is visiting. In case the user is on `*`, the menu should contain a link to `Page 1` and `Page 2`. In case the user is on `**` the menu should contain the links to `Page 1.1`, `Page 1.2` and `Page 1.3`

Right now I have that:

```
lib.navaside = HMENU
lib.navaside {
  entryLevel = 1
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="menu">|</ul>
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu__item">|</li>
      wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
    }
  }
}
```

But that always displays links to `Page 1` and `Page 2`, no matter which page the user is on. So would need something like:

```
entryLevel = currentlevel + 1
```

What is the »typoscript-way« to do that?

Comment: Is this one of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919874/typo3-menu-how-to-set-entrylevel-dynamic

Answer (score 0):

`entryLevel` does not mark the starting position for the menu itself, but the level you need at least to be on to see the menu at all.

What you actually want is `special = directory` with a proper value, so you should remove `entryLevel` and do it like this:

```
lib.navaside = HMENU
lib.navaside {
  special = directory
  special.value.field = uid
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="menu">|</ul>
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menu__item">|</li>
      wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
    }
  }
}
```

This will render a menu of subpages to a page with the uid of the current page.